# HTML meta tag not recognised in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, viewport, meta

Been looking on the web, but it seems like I'am the only one who has this problem.

It seems to me that the

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Only works with Google Chrome, but doesn't on Firefox (both in Device mode).

Anyone know the reason for this, and perhaps a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox has support for [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) in their mobile version 1.1 onwards. Can you try after removing the "user-scalable" attribute

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

My guess is this user-scalable attribute is not supported and causing problem.

Comment: Thnx, the problem was actually that Firefox doesn't have a device mode, but it just uses smaller resolution